# Wordpress navbar with logo in middle

Tags: theme-development, menus, logo

I was searching for something that could help me with query but could not find a understandable solution.
What I am trying to do is show the site logo in the center of menu. I have checked the split option and others but they all lack the responsiveness or we need to setup 2 menus (left and right sides of logo) to get 1 final menu.

Is there any better solution out there? An example will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Walker to make it easier. Please read more detail to know it and try to research again :D

Link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Tut: https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/

And this is my website, I completed it using Menu Walker. The link below :D

Link: https://frankfurt-am-sein.de/